# sproutvideo play button doesn't work on apple devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

I use `sproutvideo` to store videos, I tried to set up a control bar using jQuery UI, but the play button does not work on Apple devices like iPhone and iPad.
This is is the working [link](http://sproutvideo-examples.s3.amazonaws.com/custom_player/final/index.html).
That's my code.

```js
var videoPlayer;
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.progress').slider({
  value: 0,
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  animate: true,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
   videoPlayer.seek(ui.value);
  }
 });
 
 var _duration = 0, _playing = false, _volume = 1, _fullscreen = false;

 var videoPlayer = new SV.Player({videoId: 'e898d2b5111be3c860'});
 
 videoPlayer.bind('ready', function(event){
  _duration = event.data.duration;
  $(".progress").slider("option", "max", _duration);
 });

 videoPlayer.bind('progress', function(event){
  $('.progress').slider("option", "value", (event.data.time));
 });

 videoPlayer.bind('pause', function(event){
  _playing = false;
  $('.play-pause i').removeClass('icon-pause').addClass('icon-play');
 });

 videoPlayer.bind('play', function(event){
  _playing = true;
  $('.play-pause i').removeClass('icon-play').addClass('icon-pause');
 });

 videoPlayer.bind('volume', function(event){
  _volume = event.data;
  if (_volume == 1) {
   $('.volume i').removeClass('icon-volume-off').addClass('icon-volume-up');
  } else if (_volume == 0) {
   $('.volume i').removeClass('icon-volume-up').addClass('icon-volume-off');
  }
 });

 $('.play-pause a').click(function(){
  if (!_playing) {
   videoPlayer.play();
  } else {
   videoPlayer.pause();
  }
 });

 $('.volume a').click(function(){
  if (_volume == 0) {
   _volume = 1;
  } else {
   _volume = 0;
  }
  videoPlayer.setVolume(_volume);

 });

 $('.fullscreen a').click(function(){
  var elem = $('.player')[0];
  if (!_fullscreen) {
   if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
   } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
   } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
   }
   _fullscreen = true;
  } else {
   if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
   } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
   } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
   }
   _fullscreen = false;
  }
 });

});
```

```css
html {
 background: url(http://4walled.cc/src/7e/7e857f5f0db89a65aabcc6ed527a2743.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

.player {
 width: 640px;
 height: 403px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 50px auto;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #CCC;
}

.video {
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top: 0;
 bottom:43px;
}

.control {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.toolbar {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
 padding: 13px 0 13px;

}

.control a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
}

.progress-container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 43px;
 right: 79px;
 width: auto;
}
.volume, .fullscreen {
 float: right;
}

.player:-webkit-full-screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://c.sproutvideo.com/player_api.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="player">
   <div class="video">
    <iframe class='sproutvideo-player' type='text/html' src='https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/e898d2b5111be3c860/546cd1548010aaeb?type=sd&noBigPlay=true&showcontrols=false' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0'></iframe>
   </div>
   <div class="toolbar">
    <div class="control play-pause"><a href="#"><i class="icon-play"></i></a></div>
    <div class="progress-container">
     <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="control fullscreen"><a href="#"><i class="icon-fullscreen"></i></a></div>
    <div class="control volume"><a href="#"><i class="icon-volume-up"></i></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Safari doesn't allow for the `play()` method on a `<video>` to be called unless it's triggered by a `MouseEvent`. Since the SproutVideo player API uses `Window.postMessage()` to communicate with the player iframe, the `MouseEvent` is lost and Safari will not allow the `play()` function to be called. This is also a problem for the YouTube javascript API, the Vimeo javascript API, and just about any API that communicates with an iframe based video player that uses an iframe.

Unfortunately there is no work around at this time. A good interim solution would be conditionally hide the custom player controls on iOS devices and use the native video player instead.